# Typescript definition of function with property

Tags: typescript, ramda.js

I'm writing a d.ts file for ramda. The lib has a function `mapObj` and `mapObj.idx`.

```
interface RamdaStatic {
 ...
  mapObj(
    fn: Function,
    obj: any
  ): any;
  ...
}
```

My question is how to add mapObj.idx that has a similar type def? I am aware of [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766528/build-a-function-object-with-properties-in-typescript), but that requires a seperate interface and I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of saying "*`mapObj` is a function*", say "*`mapObj` can be called like a function and it has additional properties*":

```
interface RamdaStatic {
  // ...
  mapObj: {
    (fn: (value: any) => any, obj: any): any;
    idx: (fn: (value: any, key: string, obj: any) => any, obj: any) => any;
  }
  // ...
}
```

You might be able to add more type parameters to this definition to make it more useful.