# Typescript idioms around adding properties to methods inline with the method definition

Tags: attributes, typescript

Are there any idioms in typescript to define properties to methods in a class inline with the method definition?

I'm looking for something similar to .NET attributes.

Here's an example of what I've got so far

```
class FooController {
    foo(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
        res.send(JSON.stringify({ loc: 'FooController::foo 2 here '+req.params.fooId }));
    }
    bar(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
        res.send(JSON.stringify({ loc: 'FooController::bar here' }));
    }
}
FooController.prototype.foo['route'] = '/foo/:fooId';
FooController.prototype.foo['verb'] = 'get';
FooController.prototype.bar['route'] = '/bar';
FooController.prototype.bar['verb'] = 'post';
```

where a different function will consume FooController and interrogate the method attributes to set up a routing table before any of the FooController methods are invoked.

I don't like the distance between my method definitions and my property definitions, especially as my methods get larger and supporting functions sit in between the two.

Is there anything better I can do here? If there are different language features I should be using to express this other than properties, I'm open to that. I'm especially interested if the solution retains type safety.

I did review [build a function object with properties in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766528/build-a-function-object-with-properties-in-typescript) but I don't think the solutions in there are a good match because of the late binding and object method requirements.

I'm using typescript compiler version 1.0.3 with Visual Studio 2013 Update 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to keep type safety on your route methods is to define an interface:

```
interface IRoute {
    (req: express.Request, res: express.Response): void;

    route?: string;
    verb?: string;
}
```

Then define your routing methods as properties that implement the `IRoute` interface. Then you can use the constructor to define the additional `route` and `verb` properties:

```
class FooController {

    constructor(){
        // Type-safety on these properties:
        this.foo.route = '/foo/:fooId';
        this.foo.verb = 'get'

        this.bar.route = '/bar';
        this.bar.verb = 'post';
    }

    // Use fat-arrow syntax to bind the scope to this instance.
    foo: IRoute = (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
        this.bar(req, res);
    }

    bar: IRoute = (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
        // TypeScript knows about the additional properties on `this.foo`.
        this.foo.route;

        res.send(JSON.stringify({ loc: 'FooController::bar here' }));
    }

}
```

You might still have a bit of "distance" between the constructor and the route methods, but the benefits are:

- You gain type-safety
- You don't have to fiddle around with the `FooController.prototype['foo']...`
- It's all self-contained in the class definition

[Here's the above example in the TypeScript playground.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%09interface%20IRoute%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09(req%3A%20express.Request%2C%20res%3A%20express.Response)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%09route%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09%09verb%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09class%20FooController%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%09constructor()%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09%2F%2F%20Type-safety%20on%20these%20properties%3A%0D%0A%09%09%09this.foo.route%20%3D%20'%2Ffoo%2F%3AfooId'%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09this.foo.verb%20%3D%20'get'%0D%0A%09%09%09%0D%0A%09%09%09this.bar.route%20%3D%20'%2Fbar'%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09this.bar.verb%20%3D%20'post'%3B%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%09foo%3A%20IRoute%20%3D%20(req%3A%20express.Request%2C%20res%3A%20express.Response)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09this.bar(req%2C%20res)%3B%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20IRoute%20%3D%20(req%3A%20express.Request%2C%20res%3A%20express.Response)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09%2F%2F%20TypeScript%20knows%20about%20the%20additional%20properties%20on%20%60this.foo%60.%0D%0A%09%09%09this.foo.route%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20res.send(JSON.stringify(%7B%20loc%3A%20'FooController%3A%3Abar%20here'%20%7D))%3B%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09module%20express%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%2F%2F%20Throwaway%20module%20definition%20to%20keep%20the%0D%0A%09%09%2F%2F%20compiler%20happy%20for%20this%20example.%0D%0A%09%09export%20interface%20Request%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09params%3B%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%09export%20interface%20Response%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09send%3B%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09var%20route%20%3D%20new%20FooController()%3B%0D%0A%09console.log('foo.verb%3D'%2C%20route.foo.verb)%3B%0D%0A)

Comment: `this.foo.route = ...` in the constructor means each instance of the class will redefine the routes in the prototype. It's not elegant. [A pure JavaScript solution, without classes, is better](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=var%20r%3B%0D%0Ar.foo%20%3D%20%28req%3A%20express.Request%2C%20res%3A%20express.Response%29%20%3D%3E%20{%0D%0A%09res.send%28JSON.stringify%28{%20loc%3A%20%27FooController%3A%3Afoo%202%20here%20%27%2Breq.params.fooId%20}%29%29%3B%0D%0A}%0D%0Ar.foo.route%20%3D%20%27%2Ffoo%2F%3AfooId%27%3B%0D%0Ar.foo.route%20%3D%20%27get%27%3B%0D%0A).

Comment: But I've +1ed the answer of Basarat, it looks nice for a solution with a class.

Comment: Thanks, I'd considered that, but decided to go with a straight translation of kkost's example. I figure these types of route/controller classes aren't instantiated very often so having the clarity of a self-contained class  outweighs the route redefinition in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks - marked as accepted.  What I do like about it is the better type safety and encapsulating the concerns in the class definition. I would like it better if I could interrogate properties before I instanced an object (my pattern is establish route from method properties, and then fulfill route with a new controller object) and if the properties could be established in the exact same space as the method. I think TypeScript Decorators (mentioned by @basarat) will get me there when they are available to me.

Answer (score 4):

This is an ideal candidate for TypeScript Decorators : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2249. Your code refactored:

```
class FooController {
    @route(/*put your config here*/)
    foo(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
        res.send(JSON.stringify({ loc: 'FooController::foo 2 here '+req.params.fooId }));
    }
    @route(/*put your config here*/)
    bar(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
        res.send(JSON.stringify({ loc: 'FooController::bar here' }));
    }
}
```

Note that you will need TypeScript 1.5 which should be released very shortly.

Comment: Thanks! This seems like a perfect solution for my problem, and I'll certainly look into it when I can use it.