# typescript: functions with attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm having problems with the piece of code below:

```
CoreModule.filter('translateEnum', ['$parse', '$translate', function(
  $parse: angular.IParseService,
  $translate: angular.translate.ITranslateService
) {
  var translateFilter = function (translationId, namespace, interpolateParams, interpolation): string {
    if (!translationId) {
      return '';
    } else {
      if (!angular.isObject(interpolateParams)) {
        interpolateParams = $parse(interpolateParams)(this)
      }
      return $translate.instant( namespace + '.' + translationId, interpolateParams, interpolation)
    }
  }
  translateFilter.$stateful = true;
  return translateFilter;
}]);
```

I'm getting compilation error constantly:

```
>> app/modules/core/filters/filters.ts(47,19): error TS2339: Property '$stateful
' does not exist on type '(translationId: any, namespace: any, interpolateParams
: any, interpolation: any) => string'.
```

The problem is that I need to assing `$stateful: boolean` property to a function object and I've got no idea how to do this in typescript.

---

Here are some tries I've done, but all of them failed:

```
interface StatefulFunction {
  (translationId, namespace, interpolateParams, interpolation): string;
  $stateful: boolean;
}
```

or

```
interface StatefulFunction {
  (...args: any[]): any;
  $stateful: boolean;
}
```

or even

```
interface StatefulFunction extends Function {
  $stateful: boolean;
}
```

Comment: Could you try `var translateFilter:any`

Comment: @vmaksym no ****ing way. TypeScript's aim is not to avoid type checking by using `any`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
interface StatefulFunction {
    (): string;
    $stateful: boolean;
}

var translateFilter = <StatefulFunction>function (/*...*/) {
    /*...*/
};
```

Adapted from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18640025/373655