# Function objects in Typescript d.ts

Tags: typescript

I am trying to map a library (not written by me) to a .d.ts file. It has an object that is a function but that has properties (some of them also functions), like this:

```
var asd = function () { return 1; };
asd.two = function () { return 2; };
asd.three = 'three';
```

How can I write the type of asd in a .d.ts file? How to specify that it is a function that returns a number and that has two properties, one a function returning a number and one that is a string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [build a function object with properties in typescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766528/build-a-function-object-with-properties-in-typescript)

Comment: @mk. I think that question is slightly different because it's not about definition files, but I do believe I saw this question somewhere else before... I just can't find it.

Comment: @DavidSherret Yep, you're right, it's not exact, though the answers are just about the same except for `declare`. I updated my answer in that other question to cover .d.ts files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html):

```
declare function asd(): number;

declare module asd {
    function two(): number;
    var three: string;
}
```

Tests:

```
let num: number = asd();
num = asd.two();
asd.three = "str";
```