# Typescript Global.d.ts module definition for function attached to other function

Tags: javascript, typescript, .d.ts

long story short, I have a npm module which exports a function and other function attached to exported function:

```
// @mycompany/module
...
const someTool = (options) => {
  // do some cool stuff
};

someTool.canUseFeature1 = () => {
  return canUseSomeFeature1();
};

module.exports = someTool;
```

In my client application, I need to declare type for exported function `someTool` and for attached function `someTool.canUseFeature1`.

I'm declaring the type in a file Global.d.ts:

```
declare module '@mycompany/module' {
  export default function (options: any): any;
}
```

The question, how to declare `someTool.canUseFeature1` in similar manner?
The closest answer I found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35086682/function-objects-in-typescript-d-ts), but I could not adapt it to external module.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution:

Function in js literally is an object, so it worth to use [type declaration for objects](https://typescript-site-76.ortam.vercel.app/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#objects-with-properties). And this approach works.

Resulting solution for my case:

```
declare module '@mycompany/module' {
  function someTool(options: any): any;
  namespace someTool {
    function canUseFeature1() : boolean;
  }
  export = someTool
}
```