# How to safely use function properties in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have some code similar to the following and TypeScript complains about the property `__cache`:
`Property '__cache' does not exist on type '() => number'.(2339)`

```
function getNextValue(): number {
   if (typeof getNextValue.__cache === 'undefined') {
      getNextValue.__cache = 0;
   }

   return ++getNextValue.__cache;
}
```

How can this be correctly typed to declare a property `__cache: number|undefined` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build a function object with properties in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766528/build-a-function-object-with-properties-in-typescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve the desired behaviour would be to use an arrow function instead like this:

```
interface NextValueFn {
  (): number
  __cache?: number;
}

const getNextValue: NextValueFn = (): number => {
   if (typeof getNextValue.__cache === 'undefined') {
      getNextValue.__cache = 0;
   }

   return ++getNextValue.__cache;
}
```

[On Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIQB5gGpwDYCuEAYiMgN4BQyyAFAJQBcyIBAtgEbTXID6vCRAAsIAfmatO0ANyUAvpUoIA9iADOYZAHMIYdFlyEIzfTnxFSyALx0mLdlyjWAfBR7JgMOmACeABwhlLx09TDMjADp%20QQQRaysbAHICEAATCBhQCFTE%20jcaAu1dU0MiKIFhFBsABlkChXcoXQIoMgBqNpCS8whymJFZOSA)

Getting the same behaviour using plain functions is not possible at the moment, this issue has been raised with the typescript maintainers and is being tracked here [#34319](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34319).