# Typescript: How to dynamically add a method to a function with autocompletion?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, instance

Being new to Typescript I cannot understand how to attach a method to a function. The code works but the types are not exported correctly for autocompletion. Can please somebody help and tell me what I am doing wrong?

```js
import * as CSS from 'csstype';

export type AsType = 'div' | 'span' | 'main';
export interface InstanceType {
  /**
  * Set HTML tag
  * @param as Tag or component
  */
  as: (tagName: AsType) => any;
}

// base has methods render(props: CSS.Properties) and as(a: AsType)
const boxInstance = new Base();

function attachMethods(Component, instance) {
  Component.as = function as(asProp: AsType) {
    return instance.as(asProp);
  }
}

function Box(props: CSS.Properties): InstanceType {
  return boxInstance.render(props);
}

attachMethods(Box, boxInstance);
```

In another module Box is imported like this, but autocompletion does not work. I use Microbundle so the *.d.ts should be created correctly. Box renders a react component.

```js
import { Box } from 'package';

// autocompletion or JSDoc does not work here
const Boxi = Box.as('div');
// returns <div>Box</div>
<Boxi>Box</Boxi>
```

Also tried Object.assign liked described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766528/build-a-function-object-with-properties-in-typescript) without any change.

```
const Box: InstanceType = Object.assign(
 (props: CSS.properties) => boxInstance.render(props),
 {
   as: function as(asProp: AsType) {
    return instance.as(asProp);
   }
 }
)
```

[**Typescript Playground**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wMIGUtwGZQQhwDkAxqqjAJ5gCmJAUKJLHAEp3JkwA0cAbzhkoXGHQCiAGzog6AO3gBffIWIlR3GE0Y16mHOwCuM9AF4DWAHQAFQvVjA6qAGLIpUgEbcA1gB5GODgqKGB5AHM4AB84eSMQTzooaLgAQSgoZGo-ELDImLiEpJS4jwA+Rgq9OjTzOAApLAANKwBJRVD5VGAyaVkFGFQAbmZFJLxuGvaqZHkyOgAVWhqBQLgAegQENcQgrDp4AAsYECk4GGRI6GEiSHkBnaQ4AAEwZEziNDgAWjgFy7g1zItwg90UjyCz1EMCMUC6N3AoIGVjgAFkjFQ4IkEZ4wnQACZwADuwBgh2JpMOAAoAJQQl50AAeyHAMnpwK68AwtzgFgAQhBGVY0FSSCBkGESHSgrs4H5ueAyuKwn51gqwBUZQh1ms0AAuOBU-W1Gm8spwaYXOaLZYjJSjcRQCbzTAgsEwJb6JnieT49CW2bzT0rNZUsD2VAG7BYYymGkG2bUO2MFNkKRodB8tAhmVwORQcIEuwQMCRlDyJMp3MckJGHjQWmCHa586HYCoKz5wv44ul3mCJQjXP25si5AG3IRU2rFsysntztJbu9upCKzr+cdrtFiP8Y3IOCD5u56Gw+TCTTiPpyRRGmlDmUjk8KfFJMMRqOGEzOafHudtrclx3EtVzgdcrHDEDDz-IJTzhC8xEkGQbxgUV8WAAA3KVm3te0a3gTxBX7e4iTgLNUDoWkRkYdZ1j+AAJVpcHYCRUQAeQANQkXAJHYdg2PYLAaLo-CyMFKM3QGYN+zwIw5hgYBQTExl3xAg0V1-WiZTg89CKFURfTfSDS3vYTDxQdB1SRRRg2o2T5MU88BRU4yy2jWMfwkxF3Wkmc4B0rFBSsAzXygVSTLtOAU3snhHJQGALjIQ5UQOQ4ID9BYIADa0-AWOBvRff1OUDG16DKKk1mBbyBgNBZeDWMIZmtA1sqDZZGHjP44AAMgtYrrV8tZNny1ApDCeB5Agb43g+b5NEoYBwnkA0AG0ACIkkIKA1v4IQ1tctaDQmKQKMPABdRAdUqyTFGFOoYoUpTkCNMtUlQX9nxheDGqteY7pe0ygiPWCDjPBE7gGCzy0rEcHri5AEu4ZLUvS1BMtaugOIAJly8rruqxRavqoIfpKlr+ra+gOtqnq+qaymczgNjPAAKzoHgrFfPA8V7JIaCpKqIcUfgSDQEhdubDD3CMOgDReg03tNMxzVJ61-rQaVD0B-zQfgwXrPgL5E2TMy2KkfEMKSbpQUYBHEuRslUfRinKOc-g9NMrTmbZjmuZ5+w+eoOBLaga35FtxGkpSx2Mqyl3sapN3AsZUyzIAOWcBSIkYUTnOAftnP+khUDeeRsLMjB3BkQl0NEHgpGoRg4aUlxgFD+BGz8gK-GcsoFkz1Ve8Ye0gibuTYqU-YOUJTu1m7vO+4H9YF+HoA)

**Edited 28.08**
According to the answer from Aluan Haddad the parameter name for JSDoc was wrong. It should be. But JSDoc was not working because the InstanceType was not correct. Please see answer from ccarton.

```
* @param tagTame - Tag or component
```

**Edited 29.08**
A workaround tried. This removes typescript errors and TSDoc works.

```
interface ComponentType extends InstanceType {
 (props: CSS.Properties): any // or ReturnType<typeof render> function
}

const Box: ComponentType = function Box(props: CSS.Properties) {
  return box.render(props);
} as ComponentType;
```

**Playgrounds**
Settings all types to any I still end up with either [cannot invoke as function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wMIGUtwGZQQhwDkAxqqjAJ5gCmJAUKJLHAN5xlR3Ix0BRADZ0QdAHbwAvvkLESPZGRhNGNephwAlAK4j0AXk1YAdAAVC9WMDqoAYsiFCARkoDWAHkZw4VKMHEAczgAHzhxHRBnOihQuABBKChkag8-AOCwiKiYuIinAD5GIvU6BMM4NzpqCDw4ACksAA0TAElJf3FUYDJhUQkYVABuZkkYvCUy9qpkcTI6ABVaMvZvOAB6BAQ1xB8sOngACxgQITgYZGDoLiJIcQGdpDgAATBkZOI0OABaOAXLuDXMi3CD3SSPHzPHgwHRQLo3cCggYmOAAWR0VDg0QRzgCdAAJnAAO7AGCHYmkw4ACgAlBCXnQAB7IcAienArrwDC3OBGABCEEZJjQVJIIGQARIdJ8uzgHm54AK4oCHnWCrARRlCHWazQAC44FT9eUabyCihxNQRlJGKN+FAJvNMCCwTA7OIOGsqWBLKgDdgsLp9DSDbNqIwbWpls7Ea6lhojOqkZJ3XAAGRwMzvGDARweaYXOaLZZFRhkIRodB8tArHZwMRQQIEiwQMB+i1W20ym6cqA6ZTQWme7vdsnAVAmBtN-Ettu8jhSEbdyPdkXIA3xVCm1YjmVjidT5u++ecExn-eTmLT2eoAA0KHbyDgi7r3ehsI93F4-D6YkkRppJcZRXGUeHEfEYm9f1tD0WxTVDS1h13c5DnHS9GyPVsKlPM8wGfV9QIOD8uEUH8RD-GBRXxYAADcpTrG1I1tDlMWcQV53uIk4GrVA6FpEYy1BTEBUZf0XQGeMygzLNrDzAtZnmSTzSMb1fWgwNYK3M0kPfOEsUFEwwIgqBVKwwCI1tPAdDmHNQRQGALjIQ5UQOQ4IHxVAFggeSizlBYCipNZgVjAYEOoW81gCGYizCxh4L+dM4B8xTox3OAAHlnAAKzoZQTAgvA8VnGIaCpYK7gGe8SDQEh7zSnwaMcHQ6ANI1203U0DHNKLC3mYVUDa6Vn3MnxdM-cTJAfDtrVtPhHOc1z3M87zOQUviRPvNjGXMxh1nWOAADlbBzIJBM5bjBWAecRP60VUDecR6LO1AIBEEwhAgQIqRE4AaSAA) or [as is missing in type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wMIGUtwGZQQhwDkAxqqjAJ5gCmJAUKJLHAN5xlR3Ix0BRADZ0QdAHbwAvvkLESPZGRhNGNephwAlAK4j0AXk1YAdAAVC9WMDqoAYsiFCARkoDWAHkZw4VKMHEAczgAHzhxHRBnOihQuABBKChkag8-AOCwiKiYuIinAD5GIvU6BMM4NzpqCDw4ACksAA0TAElJf3FUYDJhUQkYVABuZkkYvCUy9qpkcTI6ABVaMvZvOAB6BAQ1xB8sOngACxgQITgYZGDoLiJIcQGdpDgAATBkZOI0OABaOAXLuDXMi3CD3SSPHzPHgwHRQLo3cCggYmOAAWR0VDg0QRzgCdAAJnAAO7AGCHYmkw4ACgAlBCXnQAB7IcAienArrwDC3OBGABCEEZJjQVJIIGQARIdJ8uzgHm54AK4oCHnWCrARRlCHWazQAC44FT9eUabyCihxNQRlJGKN+FAJvNMCCwTA7OIOGsqWBLKgDdgsLp9DSDbNqIwbWpls7Ea6lhojOqkZJ3XAAGRwaYXOaLZa2shCNDoPloFY7OBiKCBAkWCBgP0Wq22mU3TlQHTKaC0z0tltk4CoEyV6v42v13kcKQjFuRlsi5AG+KoU2rXsy-uD4c130TzgmfcbocxEdj1AAGhQDeQcCn5Zb0NhHu4vH4fTEkiNNOnMtnMp44nxGJvX9bQ9FsU1Q0tHs13OQ4ByPKttzrCo933MAbzvP8DkfLhFFfER3xgUV8WAAA3KVyxtSN81BTFnEFCd7iJOAS1QOhaRGRgOUxAVGX9F0BnjMoMzMd4YGARwPCzWZ5iE80jG9X0QMDMDlzNaCHzhLFBRMf9AKgRTkK-CNbTwHQ5nE0EUBgC4yEOVEDkOCB8VQBYIGknM5QWAoqTWYFYwGSDqDPNYAhmHMgsYCC-nTTNORk3MNFXOAAHlnAAKzoZQTEAvA8THGIaCpfy7gGC8SDQEgL2SnxSMcHQ6ANI0GyXU0DHNMLs3mYVUGa6Ub2MnxNKfATJEvRtrVtPhbPsxznNc9z4pzKleIvejGWMxh1nWOAADlbHEoIuNo+BeOACdeJ60VUDecQKOOroIBEEwhAgQIVsFYAaSAA).

Comment: The parameter names are different.

Comment: Thank for the feedback. Did you mean *AsType*? It was wrongly written as *As*. It is a simplified example.

Comment: I mean that the JSDoc comment refers to a parameter name that is unspecified

Comment: thanks again. That was also a typo. Added part of box.d.ts to the question. **as** seems to be missing from **namespace**.

Comment: It should be `@param tagName` since you are documenting a parameter named `tagName`

Comment: thank you! After applying the solution from @ccarton TSDoc is also working.

Comment: Ok, looking at the playground link there are a lot of problems with that code. You're using `Base` as if it implements `InstanceType` but it doesn't. The signatures for the `as` functions are not the same. Also, `Box` says it returns `ComponentType` but it actually returns `Base.render()` which is not `ComponentType` but another React type. You should read the error messages carefully, they actually provide a lot of information about the problems if you make the effort to decipher them.

Comment: @ccarton Yes I try to, but being a newbie it is sadly not so easy. If I put all types to any I still end up in a rabbit hole. I provided to playgrounds to my answer. It would be very kind of you if you can provide a playground that shows how to dynamically attach a method to a callable function.

Answer (score 0):

If you change `attachMethods` to return the modified object you can achieve what you want with a bit of type casting. We also should use `Object.defineProperty` as the safest way to modify an existing object:

```
function attachMethods<T> (component: T, instance: InstanceType): T & InstanceType {
  Object.defineProperty(component, 'as', {
      value: (asProp: AsType) => instance.as(asProp)
  })
  return component as any
}
   
function BoxFunction (props: CSS.Properties): InstanceType {
  return boxInstance.render(props);
}

const Box = attachMethods(BoxFunction, boxInstance);
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this. Autocompletion/JSDoc still does not work. Do I need to do something special for autocompletion to work or is it enough having *.d.ts files? Get a TS error **Property 'as' does not exist on type 'T'**. namespace declaration has not changed, doest it need to?

Comment: @EspenFinnesand  Note that I'm using `component['as']` instead of `component.as`. That was to avoid that error.

Comment: I tried that also but got **Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"as"' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.**

Comment: @EspenFinnesand If you can provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (a reproducible example), either in the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) or elsewhere then I will have a closer look.

Comment: Thank you. It is an OSS project. Updated it to your answer with a twist: **attachMethods(BoxFunction as InstanceType, boxInstance)**. That seem to work. Is that a good solution. [attachMethods](https://github.com/secretlifeof/juhuui/blob/master/src/base/attachMethodsToInstance.ts), [Box](https://github.com/secretlifeof/juhuui/blob/master/src/box.ts) and [types](https://github.com/secretlifeof/juhuui/blob/master/src/types.ts). If it is more practical for you I can make a mcve?

Comment: @EspenFinnesand That might not work because then it might not let you just call `Box(props)` because it might not know that `Box` is a function. I can't tell from what you've provided why it would think the type was unknown, it is defined and known right there before the call, so there are some other factors in play.

Comment: You are right. Calling Box directly did not work. Added a solution to my answer that remove typescript errors. I will try to put together an MCVE over the next days.

Comment: @EspenFinnesand I've realized that `Object.defineProperty` is the better way to implement `attachMethods` and might solve this issue. I've updated the answer, give this new version a try.

Comment: I tried that now but it did not change. Added a typescript playground to my question. Hope that make things easier.