# How can I build a self-referential function property API in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to build an API, [inspired by jest `it` function](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/2fd45230f39e1a82576f5ea25be9759854a5fbce/types/jest/index.d.ts#L372), which will look like this:

```
Typescript

interface Something {
    (param: number): void
    modifier: Something
    anotherModifier: Something
}
```

So I'll be able to use it like this:

```
s()
s.modifier()
s.anotherModifier.modifier()
```

If I was building it in pure JS, I'd make a few different functions, and then give them properties that would point towards one another:

```
const pure = (a) => {}
const modifier = (a) => {}
const anotherModifier = (a) => {}

for(const handler of [pure, modifier, anotherModifier]) {
    handler.modifier = modifier
    handler.anotherModifier = anotherModifier
}
```

But in TS I can't do this, as an object has to have all required properties when it's created, so I'm forced to use casts, but: (1) it is ugly, and (2) I feel like there's a much easier pattern to construct this.

So, is there a **standard** and **type safe** pattern (or library) which is **commonly used** to construct objects like these in Typescript? Maybe there are existing open source projects written in Typescript which can serve as example for such task?

---

This question is building on [question about function properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766528/build-a-function-object-with-properties-in-typescript) — it's not duplicate, I need to do more things which are more specific.

Comment: *"I need to do more things which are more specific"* - what things? Can you give an example that _wouldn't_ work with the proposed solutions?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think I already did. The question I link to just adds properties, which are not self-referential.

Comment: I don't see why that means you can't use the same pattern of e.g. an IIFE where the return value is fully constructed. *"I'm forced to use casts"* - yes, because what you create initially _isn't a `Something`_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe my question specifically asks if there's a less ugly way. May there really isn't, which would also be an answer to my question. I can use casts, yes; but I'm used to cast things in typed languages only after making sure that no other solution exists.

Comment: What would "less ugly" be? That seems quite opinion-based. And it's a little disingenuous to claim your needs are more specific in some way when you just don't like it.

Comment: In this context, "less ugly" would be "without casts", because in my opinion (completely agree about it being opinion based) every cast is a promise that you make to a type system that you now responsible for and have to keep, and I try to keep amount of promises I make in my code to a minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i guess you can achive that with some boilerplate assignments:

```typescript
interface Something {
    (param: number): void
    modifier: Something
    anotherModifier: Something
}

function getSomething(): Something {
    function anotherModifier(a: number) {}
    function something(a: number) {}
    function modifier(n: number) {}

    something.modifier = modifier
    something.anotherModifier = anotherModifier

    modifier.modifier = modifier
    modifier.anotherModifier = anotherModifier

    anotherModifier.modifier = modifier
    anotherModifier.anotherModifier = anotherModifier

    return something
}

const s = getSomething()

s(1)
s.modifier(1)
s.anotherModifier.modifier(1)
```

Comment: I didn't know that Typescript compiler actually changes type of `something` with each line that assigns it a property, and yet I somehow considered myself a pretty advanced Typescript user. This is awesome. Thanks a lot for your answer!