# Declare object property in typescript definition file

Tags: javascript, typescript, module

I have a function that returns a boolean. The function also has a property `errors` as an array. It is in a module.

example.js

```js
exports["example"] = myFunc;
function myFunc(data) {
  return true;
}
myFunc.errors = ['error']
```

I can define the function return signature in a typescript `.d.ts` file;

example.d.ts

```
export declare function uploadedFile(data: any): boolean;
```

but I don't know how to define the functions `errors` property so that it should return a string array?

```
export declare function uploadedFile(data: any): boolean;
export declare property uploadedFile.errors: Array<string>; // ??
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766528/build-a-function-object-with-properties-in-typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare it as an object with a [call signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures):

```
export declare var uploadedFile: {
  (data: any): boolean;
  errors: string[];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To declare the property `errors` you can change the second declaration to namespace like this:

```
export declare function uploadedFile(data: any): boolean;
export declare namespace uploadedFile {
    errors: Array<String>;
}
```