# typescript type with call signature instantiation

Tags: javascript, typescript

While reading TypeScript documentation I stumbled upon this:

```
type DescribableFunction = {
  description: string;
  (someArg: number): boolean;
};

function doSomething(fn: DescribableFunction) {
  console.log(fn.description + " returned " + fn(6));
}
```

How can I create and instance of DescribableFunction?

Comment: Am I wrong to think `Object.assign` would work pretty well?

Answer (score 2):

Edit: here's the cleaner way: [SO answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766528/build-a-function-object-with-properties-in-typescript/33392782#33392782)

I don't see how you can do it without casting. I would create a separate function for creating the `DescribableFunction`:

```
function createDesirableFunction(description: string, func: (someArg: number) => boolean): DescribableFunction {
    const result = func;
    (result as DescribableFunction).description = description;
    return result as DescribableFunction;
}
```

Here it is in action: [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhDOBjATgSwEYEN0BsIDEBXAO0WFQHtioBeKAbwCgooATBFVMcqgLinjA0xAOYBuZlAAU8CgFsIAQWQj%20xQnPQRkASn7oKFPJmISAvhMYAzEmUrVWFAMryIwABapRUq8X5wkNCxcAlseYh0GSUQqWTwAOhwKER9iePZArnCoAGooACIoZDdCZGIIVgLcqF8pADYdHXNGFptSbJQITGAIANRkbDwidvspDM5ue35BYREAGhrbfhlXZVUodU1tHRoAPigDIy7qFj1YDiDB0JGqKJYWGOJBIoRCHGBaRdIJe%20li%20DeH0w8HOmWCQzC9h06QuWXsn3GaEmVB%2092KwFK1H%20gKgwNBnHB1zsKJaZhajhcCg8XhSnW6vQQ-Suw2JxCk%20XcEBwSXyCykmEiewYjziEESySkAEYmi8MWUoEJCBAxGZGkA)