# In typescript, How to define the type for a function which holds some static props?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I define an object like this:

```
const obj = {
  func() {}
}

// Then I need to define some static props for the methods of this obj:

obj.func.prop1 = 1000;
obj.func.prop2 = 'some string';
obj.func.prop3 = () => {};
```

So, how to define the types for obj's methods?

Comment: Do you wanna define params for the methods? I am not getting your exact requirement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766528/build-a-function-object-with-properties-in-typescript. In your case that would look like this: https://tsplay.dev/NDygxm